# Program not using specified number called in another function? Can anyone spot what i'm missing here?

Tags: javascript, new-operator

i'm *very* new at javascript and coding in general so apologies if this is a dumb or obvious question.

I cant work out why this program wont print the amount of stars in the function `starNumber()`?

Once again I am certain there's a simple fix, I just don't have the experience to see it!

The amount is generated in `starNumber()` and i'm fairly sure the error is occurring in `draw()`.

Thank you :)

Full code:

```html
const shapeSize = 10
const sides = 6
let palette = []
let starAmount = []

function setup() {
 createCanvas(550,550,SVG);
 background("black")
 angleMode(DEGREES);
 rectMode(CENTER);
 palette = [
    color(255, 255, 204), //cream
    color(204, 255, 255), //blue
  color(255, 255, 102), //yellow
 ]

}

function draw() { // calls other functions
  
  noLoop();
  starNumber();
  for(let i = 0; i < starAmount; i++){
      push();
        stars();
        linesFromCenter();
      pop();
    }

  
} 


function linesFromCenter() { 
  let numShapes = randomSelect() ? sides : sides * 2 // comparison (turnery thing?)
  const strokeCol = randomPalette();
  const weight = randomSelect() ? 1 : 3;
  
  const angle = 360/numShapes;
  
  noFill();
  stroke(strokeCol);
  strokeWeight(weight);

  push();
    translate(width/2, height/2);    
    stroke(strokeCol)
    for(let i = 0; i < numShapes; i++){
      line(0, 0, 0, shapeSize/2);
      rotate(angle);
    }
  pop();
}

function stars() {

  let tran1 = floor(random(-250, 250));
  let tran2 = floor(random(-250, 250));
  
  console.log(tran1);
  console.log(tran2);

  translate(tran1, tran2);
}


// helpers

function randomSelect() { // randomly picks how many sides to the shape
  const randoOne = random(1);
  if (randoOne > 0.5) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }

}


function randomPalette() {  // colour picker
  const randoTwo = floor(random(0, palette.length));
  return palette[randoTwo];
}

function starNumber() {
 let numOfStars = floor(random(10, 25));
 console.log("number of stars:", numOfStars);
 return starAmount[numOfStars];
}

// end of helpers
```

Comment: `starAmount` is an (empty) array. What do you expect the condition `i < starAmount` to do?

Comment: Hi, its supposed to be the amount of times that the for loop runs ```stars()``` and ```linesFromCenter()```.

Comment: But it's an empty array. If you want a number, you should return something from `starNumbrr` and store this result into a variable

Comment: You call starNumber() to get the number of stars, but you don't save the answer anywhere, so your loop doesn't know how many stars to make.